# Do something on Jquery mobile page close

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I want to call a function when the dialog is closed, however for testing purposes, I am just doing an alert for now, but the following does not work.

```
 $("#fbfullpostviewpage").bind("pagehide",function(){
  alert("Dialog closed");
});
```

But the same code with a different page id works? How would I make it work for this page too?

markup:

```
 if ((post.attachment.media !== undefined) &&
     (post.attachment.media.length > 0) &&
     (post.attachment.media[0].type == "photo")) {

 markup += '<li><a href="#fbfullpostviewpage" class="item" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="e" data-inline="true" data-fullscreen="false"><img src="' + thumb_url + '">' +'<h5 style="white-space:normal;">' + name + '</h5><p>' +'posted this photo....</p><p>'+likes+'<img src="images/facebook-like-16.png"></p></a></li>';

  }else { 

 markup += '<li><a href="#fbfullpostviewpage" class="item" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="e" data-inline="true" data-fullscreen="false"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/picture">'+'<h5 style="white-space:normal;">' + name + '</h5><p>' + short_post +'....</p><p>'+likes+'<img src="images/facebook-like-16.png"></p></a></li>';
       }
```

Comment: Check to see if you're using that ID `#fbfullpostviewpage` more than once in your DOM.

Comment: @DevlshOne what do u mean more than once?

Comment: Does that ID appear more than once on the page? Element IDs must be unique. If you must repeat, use classes instead.

Comment: yh it does so I tried class but it didnt work,the id is on each item on a jquery mobile listview. so the #fbfullpostviewpage is opened everytime an item is clicked. I have edited my question to include the markup.

Comment: I also have another function in the same js file but I do a $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close'); as I don't need to do anything on close.

Comment: Are you sure that the page exists in the `DOM` at the time your binding the event? Try using [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), for example `$(document).on('pagehide', '#fbfullpostviewpage', function() { alert('Dialog closed'); });`

Comment: Is the dialog dynamically inserted into DOM? If yes, do what @jack said. For any dynamically inserted elements, use that code to bind events.

Comment: @Jack awesome thanks! :) that works! so that means the page doesnt exist on the DOM when binding the event!

Comment: @Omar yes it is dynamically inserted

Comment: Go ahead @Jack add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that your *fbfullpostviewpage* page is not part of the `DOM` at the point at which your are binding your event. What you should do in this case is to use `event delegation` instead of trying to directly bind to the page element.

Basically with event delegation what you do is bind the event to a *higher* level `DOM` element (all the way up to the `Document` if necessary, but you should generally try and bind it as close to the *target* selector as possible) that does exist at that time, and then when the event *bubbles up* the `DOM` check to see if the event matches a certain selector.

In addition to allowing you to bind events for dynamically inserted elements, event delegation is also usually more efficient since you can reduce the number of events that are bound.

For example you can use the jQuery [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function like the following

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '#fbfullpostviewpage', function() { 
    alert('Dialog closed'); 
});
```